# Django TestCase testing order

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

If there are several methods in the test class, I found that the order to execute is alphabetical. But I want to customize the order of execution. How to define the execution order?

For example: testTestA will be loaded first than testTestB.

```
class Test(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ...

    def testTestB(self):
        #test code

    def testTestA(self):
        #test code
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

A tenet of unit-testing is that each test should be independent of all others.
If in your case the code in testTestA must come before testTestB, then you could
combine both into one test:

```
def testTestA_and_TestB(self):
    # test code from testTestA
    ...
    # test code from testTestB
```

or, perhaps better would be

```
def TestA(self):
    # test code
def TestB(self):
    # test code
def test_A_then_B(self):
    self.TestA()
    self.TestB()
```

The `Test` class only tests those methods who name begins with a lower-case `test...`. 
So you can put in extra helper methods `TestA` and `TestB` which won't get run unless you explicitly call them.

Comment: +1: Done this more than once myself to chain tests together, reducing setup time.

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know, there is no way to order tests other than rename them. Could you explain why you need to run test cases in the specific order? In unit testing it usually considered as bad practice since it means that your cases are not independent.

Comment: Like, for testing create an account and all following operations on account. What might be the alternative to this approach?

Comment: @ziang: The idea is that you test only *one* operation. If you want to test operations on an account, create a dummy account, then perform one op on it & check. Do this once for each operation to test, that gives you one test per operation.

Comment: I like to logically order tests. It's not that they are dependent, but the more similar the tests (test methods I mean here) are, the closer I want to put them together. It's annoying to run tests with a failfast option (as with Django) that are not executed in the order you defined them, in case if you placed a pdb line in there it won't get triggered unless it's the alphabetically first failing test.

Comment: @sleske so you offer to copy a code for each test for account creation? Doesn't seem right to me at all, once I have to refactor tests due to code refactoring it's better to do in one place instead of editing 2000 tests right?

Comment: @holms: Well, obviously you would put the common setup code in one place, and call it. Most testing frameworks even let you define special "setup" or "init" code for just that purpose. I think in Django that would be "setUp", https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp

Comment: @sleske so funny I've came across my comment in here again while searching for same thing. I've moved function which calls 20 tests in specific order (or else other tests would fail) to `setUp()` which actually is nice.  While with writing selenium test, I need exact order of commands or else the whole 20 form procedure will fail. They can't be tested separately.

Comment: @holms: Yes, with integration tests (which Selenium tests are) ordering of tests is often useful. For Selenium tests, we use [TestNG](http://testng.org/), specifically because it runs test in the order they are listed in the config file.

Comment: Well I'm working with python world in here, in django framework, so TestNG seems to be no use to me..? :)

Comment: If function B calls A, I'd much prefer to always run a unit test on A before B. Simply because most times it's counter productive to debug B first if A fails. Therefore I'd rather see test reports in that order. How is that a bad practice?

Answer (score 8):

To update on the topic (from documentation):

> [Order in which tests are executed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/overview/#order-in-which-tests-are-executed)
>
> In order to guarantee that all **`TestCase`** code starts with a clean
>   database, the Django test runner reorders tests in the following way:
>
> - All [`TestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase) subclasses are run first.
> - Then, all other Django-based
>     tests (test cases based on [`SimpleTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase), including
>     [`TransactionTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase)) are run with no particular ordering guaranteed
>     nor enforced among them.
> - Then any other [`unittest.TestCase`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) tests
>     (including `doctests`) that may alter the database without restoring it
>     to its original state are run.
>
> **Note**: The new ordering of tests may reveal unexpected dependencies on test
>   case ordering. This is the case with doctests that relied on state
>   left in the database by a given `TransactionTestCase` test, they must be
>   updated to be able to run independently.