# Django - Serializer throwing "Invalid pk - object does not exist" when setting ManyToMany attribute where foreign keyed object does exist

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

So below I have some code that tests the functionality where someone creates a post and that post has a `hash_tag` which is "#video" in this case. The code takes the `Post` `body` and uses regex to find any word that starts with "#". If it does then it creates or gets that `HashTag` from the `HashTag` table. Then sets that list of `HashTag` to the `hash_tags` attribute under `Post`.

For some reason the `CreatePostSerializer` serializer is throwing an exception that doesn't make sense. The serializer is throwing the exception `ValidationError({'hash_tags': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid pk "[\'video\']" - object does not exist.', code='does_not_exist')]})`. The reason this doesn't make sense is because when I debug and set a breakpoint right after `except Exception as e` under `views.py` this is what I get

```
>>>e
ValidationError({'hash_tags': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid pk "[\'video\']" - object does not exist.', code='does_not_exist')]})
>>>HashTag.objects.get(pk='video')
<HashTag: HashTag object (video)>
>>>request.data['hash_tags']
['video']
```

So the `>>>` represents what I input into the debugger. I'm essentially stopped at the line `return Response...` and we can see `e` is the `ValidationError` I mentioned, but we can see that the object it claims doesn't exist does indeed exist. **Why is the serializer throwing a "ValidationError - object does not exist" when it does?**

**Note:** I have another test that does exactly the same thing and passes except no video file is being passed this leads me to believe that Django is doing something different in the case that the incoming body is `multi-part`. I also tried in the instance that there is only one hash tag to set `hash_tags`=<single hash tag> rather than a list and it worked. This is a hack though and cleaner solution is preferred.

helpers.py

```
import re

def extract_hashtags(text):
    regex = "#(\w+)"
    return re.findall(regex, text)
```

test.py

```
def test_real_image_upload_w_hash_tag(self):
    image_file = retrieve_test_image_upload_file()
    hash_tag = 'video'
    response = self.client.post(reverse('post'),
                                data={'body': f'Some text and an image #{hash_tag}',
                                      'images': [image_file]},
                                **{'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': f'bearer {self.access_token}'})
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

views.py

```
def set_request_data_for_post(request, user_uuid: str):
    request.data['creator'] = user_uuid
    post_text = request.data['body']
    hash_tags_list = extract_hashtags(post_text)
    hash_tags = [HashTag.objects.get_or_create(hash_tag=ht)[0].hash_tag for ht in hash_tags_list]

    if len(hash_tags) > 0:
        request.data['hash_tags'] = hash_tags

    return request

def create_post(request):
    user_uuid = str(request.user.uuid)
    request = set_request_data_for_post(request=request, user_uuid=user_uuid)

    try:
        serializer = CreatePostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            post_obj = serializer.save()
    except Exception as e:
        return Response(dict(error=str(e),
                             user_message=error_message_generic),
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from cheers.models import Post

class CreatePostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('creator', 'body', 'uuid', 'created', 'updated_at', 'hash_tags')
```

model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # ulid does ordered uuid creation
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=generate_ulid_as_uuid, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator")
    body = models.CharField(max_length=POST_MAX_LEN, validators=[MinLengthValidator(POST_MIN_LEN)])
    hash_tags = models.ManyToManyField(HashTag, blank=True)

class HashTag(models.Model):
    hash_tag = models.CharField(max_length=HASH_TAG_MAX_LEN, primary_key=True, validators=[
        MinLengthValidator(HASH_TAG_MIN_LEN)])
```

Comment: Try `request.data['hash_tags'] = hash_tags` → `request.data.setlist('hash_tags', hash_tags)`.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: @aaron sorry I was busy. I'll give it a try soon and let you know!

Comment: yep looks like it works! I noticed it gives an error if hash_tags is `None`. Is there a way to allow this? I also use this serializer for patching the data so sometimes I want to clear the hashtags if the edit has no `hash_tags.` If I do `request.data['hash_tags]=None` or `[]` on the set partial it throws an exception.

Comment: @aaron hmm, but it seems like my other test that was succeeding is now failing. The one without the image.

Comment: @aaron so the issue seems to be when the request doesn't include an image it's a dictionary otherwise it's an ordered dict that seems to be what the problem is stemming from.

Comment: Can you create a repro project on GitHub?

Comment: @aaron I do have a repo, but it's private there are security keys on it and what not.

Comment: Create a project without them.

Comment: @aaron I think I know what the issue is. Has to do with setting the data if it's a QueryDict or regular Dict. If you add a file Django converts request to QueryDict, which bugs out if you set wit key value i.e. `query_dict[key] = value` for manyTomany attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

under your `test/__init__.py` you have to add these lines

```
from django.db.backends.postgresql.features import DatabaseFeatures

DatabaseFeatures.can_defer_constraint_checks = False
```

There's some weird internal bug where if you operate on one table a lot with a lot of different `TestCase` classes then it'll do a DB check at the end after it's been torn down and it'll cause an error.

I'm also using factory boy (https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/orms.html) to generate my test DB, which is the main reason this issue arises. The reason I believe this is because I switched out factory boy for just using `<model>.objects.create()` and my tests stopped failing.

Comment: This seems like a bandage that solves the immediate error but covers up deeper issues in your test cases.

Comment: what makes you call it a "bandage"? Apparently this constraint_check is unnecessary.

Comment: I think the underlying issue stems from factory boy combined with test suite in Django. I extended my answer.

Comment: Disabling features often is a bandage. Here you are disabling foreign key constraints. I'm glad it works for you, but hopefully it doesn't mask some deeper issue with your tests.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice is that what it does? When this was suggested to me they just told me it defers constraint checks to the end of TestCase rather than end of each test function. That's definitely not good if it does that.

Comment: I'm probably not using the correct wording. Either way disabling or deferring feels like a bandage since it modifies the behavior of the database.

Comment: well the main issue stems from FactoryBoy to generate test data. I'll just use `model.objects.create` instead. Thanks for the heads up you probably saved me a lot of headache later. Add as an answer and I'll vote it up.

Comment: Magic! This somehow solved a `ForeignKeyViolation` with pytest fixtures having many-to-many relations (Django 4.2.4, pytest 7.4.0, pytest-django 4.5.2). Thanks!